# Trigonometric identity needed for sums involving secants

Tags: special-functions, reference-request

I am looking for a closed-form formula for the following sum:

$\displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^{N}{\frac{\sin^{2}(\frac{k\pi}{N})}{a \cdot \sin^{2}(\frac{k\pi}{N})+1}}=\sum_{k=0}^{N}{\frac{1}{a+\csc^{2}(\frac{k\pi}{N})}}$.

Is such a formula known?

Comment: You mean to sum from $k=0$ to $N$, not from $j=0$ to $k$, right?

Comment: @WillSawin: Right, thanks. Fixed it.

Comment: I recommend making the title more specific, and include the summation.  You could even change the summand to something like 1/(a + csc^2(stuff)) to make it more line-friendly.  (I wonder if change of variables would give log(some trig expression) as an answer?)  Gerhard "Ask Me About Friendly Lines" Paseman, 2013.02.18

Comment: Secant? Really? Gerhard "Was Cosecant In My Schooldays" Paseman, 2013.02.18

Comment: This is a rational function in $a$ with integer coefficients, by Galois theory. I'm not sure what sorts of closed-form functions are capable of also being rational functions of arbitrarily high degree.

Comment: @Gerhard: this co business can be co-nfusing at times.

Comment: @Will: Any way of determining this function explicitly? If I specialize $a$ to be, say, $n^{2}$, will it help?

Comment: Why write this in terms of cosec? It would seem more natural to use half-angle formulas to have $\cos$ in the denominator (and modulo adding and scaling by a constant you can assume the numerator is 1)

Comment: @YemonChoi: I think I didn't quite understand your last remark. Can you explain?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two other references to similar sums are

Bruce C. Berndt and Boon Pin Yeap, [Explicit evaluations and reciprocity theorems for finite trigonometric sums](http://www.math.uiuc.edu/~berndt/articles/trigsums.pdf), Advances in Applied Mathematics
Volume 29, Issue 3, October 2002, Pages 358--385

and

Ira Gessel, [Generating Functions and Generalized Dedekind Sums](http://www.combinatorics.org/ojs/index.php/eljc/article/view/v4i2r11), Electronic J. Combinatorics, 
Volume 4, Issue 2 (1997) (The Wilf Festschrift volume), R11.

The paper of Berndt and Yeap uses contour integration and has an extensive list of references. My paper uses elementary methods, including partial fractions.

Here are the details of the partial fraction approach:

First we convert the trigonometric sum to a sum over roots of unity.
Let $\eta_k=e^{k\pi i /N}$ and let $\zeta_k=\eta_k^2 = e^{2k\pi i/N}$.
Then 
\begin{equation*}
\csc^2(k\pi/N) = \left(\frac{2i}{\eta_k -\eta_k^{-1}}\right)^2
  =\frac{-4\eta_k^2}{(\eta_k^2-1)^2}
  =\frac{-4\zeta_k}{(\zeta_k-1)^2}.
\end{equation*}
Thus (since the summand vanishes for $k=0$) the sum is 
\begin{equation*}
\sum_{\zeta^N=1} \frac{1} {a-4\zeta/(\zeta-1)^2}
  =\sum_{\zeta^N=1} \frac{(\zeta-1)^2}{a(\zeta-1)^2 - 4\zeta}.
\end{equation*}
To apply the partial fraction method, we need to find the partial fraction expansion of 
\begin{equation*}
F(z)=\frac{(z-1)^2}{a(z-1)^2 - 4z}
\end{equation*}
Factoring the denominator shows that we can simplify things if we make the substitution 
$a=4c/(c-1)^2$, so that
\begin{equation*}
c = \frac{a+2+2\sqrt{a+1}}{a}.
\end{equation*}
Then we have
\begin{equation*}
F(z) =\frac{(c-1)^2}{4c} +\frac{(c-1)^3}{4(c+1)}\left(\frac{1}{z-c} -\frac{1}{c(cz-1)}\right)
\end{equation*}
We have 
\begin{equation*}
\sum_{\zeta^N=1} (\zeta-c)^{-1} = - \frac{Nc^{N-1}}{c^N-1}
\end{equation*}
and
\begin{equation*}
\sum_{\zeta^N=1} (c\zeta-1)^{-1} = \frac{N}{c^N-1}
\end{equation*}
So the sum is 
\begin{equation*}
\sum_{\zeta^N=1} F(\zeta) = 
   N\frac{(c-1)^2}{4c} \left(1-\frac{(c-1)}{(c+1)}\frac{(c^N+1)}{(c^N-1)}\right).
\end{equation*}
where $c=(a+2+2\sqrt{a+1})/a$.
In terms of $a$, we can simplify this a little to
\begin{equation*}
\frac{N}{a} \left(1-\frac{1}{\sqrt{a+1}}\frac{(c^N+1)}{(c^N-1)}\right).
\end{equation*}
If you really want an expression which is rational in $a$, it's possible to write this as a quotient of polynomials in $a$ that are given by generating functions.

Comment: Thanks! Eventually I found out these two papers, after aaking gHe question and learnt a lot from them. I did manage to reduce the expression to a sum of elementary fractions - but that's where I got stuck because unlike in the usual case my sum runs over only half of te roots of unity and not all of them. Do you kow of a way to surmount this difficulty?

Comment: I have edited my post to include the full solution.

Comment: This is a really great exposition but I think I stated my difficulty very poorly: I want to handle also the case when the sum runs only over the *even* numbers from $0$ to $N$ (assume $N$ itself is odd). (I'm not sure it'd be a good  idea to edit the question at this stage, so I'm stating the modification here). 

That's where I got stuck, because I don't know how to sum only over the even ones - is there another trick that handles this case?

Thanks again!

Comment: You can still try the partial fraction expansion, but it probably won't simplify as much. Is there any reason to think that there's a simple formula for this case?

Answer (score 2):

I think that the following article of our very own [Roberto Bosch Cabrera](https://mathoverflow.net/users/23528/roberto-bosch-cabrera) might come in handy:

https://www.awesomemath.org/wp-content/uploads/reflections/2008_5/article_2.pdf

Specifically, you should take a look at pages 1 & 2 of that note.

Comment: The link is dead.

Answer (score 1):

This may not be of much (any!) help, but Mathematica 7 gives a closed-form solution in terms of QPolyGamma functions:

$\frac{\psi _{e^{-\frac{2 i \pi }{n}}}^{(0)}\left(1-\frac{\log
   \left(\frac{a-2 \sqrt{a+1}+2}{a}\right)}{\log \left(e^{-\frac{2 i
   \pi }{n}}\right)}\right)-\psi _{e^{-\frac{2 i \pi
   }{n}}}^{(0)}\left(n-\frac{\log \left(\frac{a-2
   \sqrt{a+1}+2}{a}\right)}{\log \left(e^{-\frac{2 i \pi
   }{n}}\right)}+1\right)+\sqrt{a+1} n \log \left(e^{-\frac{2 i \pi
   }{n}}\right)}{a \sqrt{a+1} \log \left(e^{-\frac{2 i \pi
   }{n}}\right)}$

$+$

$\frac{\psi _{e^{-\frac{2 i \pi }{n}}}^{(0)}\left(n-\frac{\log
   \left(\frac{a+2 \sqrt{a+1}+2}{a}\right)}{\log \left(e^{-\frac{2 i
   \pi }{n}}\right)}+1\right)-\psi _{e^{-\frac{2 i \pi
   }{n}}}^{(0)}\left(1-\frac{\log \left(\frac{a+2
   \sqrt{a+1}+2}{a}\right)}{\log \left(e^{-\frac{2 i \pi
   }{n}}\right)}\right)}{a \sqrt{a+1} \log \left(e^{-\frac{2 i \pi
   }{n}}\right)}$

$\psi^{(0)}_q$ is the q-PolyGamma function.